# prettierにて、printWidthを300くらいにしているにも関わらず改行される

Tags: reactjs, react-jsx, prettier

react、typescript,  jsxといった技術スタックです。

prettierにて、printWidthを300くらいにしているにも関わらず、
jsxが以下のようになってしまいます。

```
<text>foo<text/>
```

↓

```
<text>
  foo
<text/>
```

typescript自体のコードはしっかり300になるのですが、
これはprintWidthとはなにか別の設定が必要なのでしょうか？